# Load balancing and virtual clusters

Tags: load-balancing

Last evening, I spent several hours in the datacenter installing our new load balancer, a [CoyotePoint E350GX](http://www.coyotepoint.com/products/e350.php). I've set up 3 clusters:

`nginxCluster`

- 10.0.0.10

`apacheCluster`

- 10.0.0.20

`mysqlCluster`

- 10.0.0.30

Currently, there's a box in the `apacheCluster`, with IP 10.0.0.21. From the load balancer, I can ssh to this IP fine. There's also a box in the `mysqlCluster`, with IP 10.0.0.31. I can ssh to this box from the load balancer as well.

Here's the problem. If I try to connect to mysql from the apache box to the `mysqlCluster` IP, it fails. However, I can connect to the individual box *behind* `mysqlCluster` just fine. Any ideas? More information needed?

Comment: Your link to the product has an asterisk appended to it.

Comment: *"However, I can connect to the individual box behind mysqlCluster just fine."* By "individual" box you mean 10.0.0.31 but you cannot connect to 10.0.0.30, correct?

Comment: @Nimmy Lebby Edited to remove asterisk. Correct. I can connect from 10.0.0.21 to 10.0.0.31, but not to 10.0.0.30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the CoyotePoint is expecting public IPs for the clusters. I haven't had a chance to test it, but that's what the technical support person suggested. I'll update this answer later if this works.